# Stimulsoft Report Unicode Character (Arabic Or Persian) In richText Error

Tags: unicode, report, stimulsoft

Stimulsoft Report Unicode Character (Arabic Or Persian) In rich-text below Error:
The error of compilation
The error of compilation is found in the 'Text' property of the 'RichText1' component:
Unexpected character '\'

create a rtf file and type text and variable after in richtext open this file
in preview error.

too unicode charecter Cluttered

```
این قرارداد 
ãÏíÑ1
```

Comment: Which Designer or Viewer and version do you use? Did you try the latest build?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Set the **Full Convert Expression** property of the Rich Text component to **True**.